# Bug - Getting partial results for questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions, missing-data

When processing http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/questions/1156985 I only get partial results.  Many of the missing fields are mandatory fields, including the owner of the question.

Comment: If you look at the [actual question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156985), you'll see that the owner is deleted/unregistered.

Comment: One thing that is a bit unclear in the docs is where the underlying structures are optional - or should I assume ALL are optional by default. Yes, I get that collections can be empty, but structs like Owner, I would expect to be populated when their fields are mandatory.  

Otherwise, the documentation of the structures is excellent.

Comment: See my feature request: http://stackapps.com/questions/1083/can-we-have-an-owner-name-value-in-question-answer-and-comment

Answer (score 1):

As [Dennis](https://stackapps.com/users/171/dennis-williamson) pointed out, there is no owner (effectively) on that question.

That the API does not return a displayable "no user" string in these (and related) cases is an acknowledge deficiency which will be rectified in a subsequent version.

Comment: @Rich here is where I brought up the issue: http://stackapps.com/questions/1083/can-we-have-an-owner-name-value-in-question-answer-and-comment